# How to convert a Ada.Real_TIme.Time to a string?

Tags: file-io, real-time, ada

I would like to write a [Ada.Real_Time.Time](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-D-8.html) in a file,

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Copyedit and added link; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package Ada.Real_time doesn't provide a method for the direct format.

I'd advise you to look at Ada.Calendar.Formatting.
You have a method Clock like in Ada.Real_time.
Indeed, there is a method Image(parameters : Time), which returns a String.

For more details : [Package: Ada.Calendar.Formatting](http://www.martin.dowie.btinternet.co.uk/Calendar/adabrowse/ada-calendar-formatting.html)

Comment: Finally we used Ada.Calendar.Formatting instead of `Ada.Real_Time.Clock`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Ada.Real_Time.Split` to convert an `Ada.Real_Time.Time` into (a) the number of seconds since the epoch, type `Ada.Real_Time.Seconds_Count` and (b) the fractional part, type (private) `Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span`; and you can use `Ada.Real_Time.To_Duration` to convert the fractional part into a `Duration`.

You can then use `Ada.Real_Time.Seconds_Count'Image` and `Duration'Image` to convert to `String`.

But what do you want the string for? If it's to compare when things happened in a single run, fine, but there's nothing in the language definition to say when the epoch was; it could be the time when the computer was last booted, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Invoke the Ada.Real_Time.Split() function, which converts a Time to a Seconds_Count and a Time_Span. The Seconds_Count value is the number of seconds elapsed since the epoch, and the Time_Span value is the number of (very small) Time_Units after that last second. See [D.8 Monotonic Time](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-D-8.html) (29) for details.

Seconds_Count is publicly visible in the package, and the Time_Span can be converted to a Duration via To_Duration().

Note that you can invert the process and use Time_Of() to reconstruct a Time value.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need it as readable text, but just want it saved to a file, you could try using the stream output attribute (`'Write`)