# ADA Real_time string

Tags: time, ada, real-time

Possible duplicate:
[How to convert a Ada.Real_TIme.Time to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944565)

How can I convert a Time type obtained with a Ada.Real_Time.Clock to a String type in Ada ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944565

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a Ada.Real_TIme.Time to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944565/how-to-convert-a-ada-real-time-time-to-a-string)

Comment: What makes me think someone just gave this as a homework assignment? :-)

Answer (score -1):

dude use the To_Duration to print it (using a cast Duration'Image)